# Trimming the outputs in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I made something which gets the time from https://time.is/ and shows the time. I used BeautifulSoup and urllib.request.

But I want to trim the output. I'm getting this as output and I want to remove the code part.

```
<div id="twd">07:29:26</div>
```

Program File:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://time.is/'
hdr = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)' }

req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=hdr)
res = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')
string = soup.find(id='twd')
print(string)
```

How can I get just the text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the text from the dom element with `.text` like:

```
string.text
```

#### Test Code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://time.is/'
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'}

req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=hdr)
res = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')
string = soup.find(id='twd')
print(string.text)
```

#### Results:

```
07:06:11PM
```